# Can I give custom names to the inputs to my LG 32LD HDTV?

Tags: hdtv, label

My LG HDTV lets me press the Blue button on my remote to select from a small set of names for my inputs, generic things like "Game" and "PC". Is there a hidden way to write custom names for my inputs, or does the TV simply not have this feature?

Comment: We don't deal with pure TV questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TV in particular likely does not have this feature. When cycling through the menu which gives you the generic input names you mentioned earlier, press on the blank one, if there is one, and it should give you a option to enter a custom name. If not, then your TV isn't capable of such a feature.

From my experience, the only TVs to have this feature are a select few Panasonics. None of the Samsung, Sony, or LG TVs I have worked on have had this feature.

Comment: Yeah, only my friend's Sharp Aquos seems to have this feature.

Comment: I Don't think that the people who develop these TVs like to give end users too many features due to most of them not knowing exactly how they work and possibly screwing up their TVs. While a simple custom naming feature probably wouldn't screw anything up, they still don't want to give the users too much control.

Comment: @BenFranchuck That's not accurate. As I said, my landlord's TV lets you write custom labels. More expensive and newer TVs add more features.

Comment: i know. What im saying is that some developers don't add such features for that reason. Sure, some do, but others don't.